# setHidden not working for UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, subview

I have a subclass of `UIView` called `InvitedView`. It is instantiated in `viewDidLoad` like this:

**ViewController.m**

```
invitedView = [[InvitedView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 244, 120, 80)];
invitedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:156.0f/255.0f green:214.0f/255.0f blue:215.0f/255.0f alpha:0.9f];      
[self.view addSubview:invitedView];
[invitedView setHidden:YES];
```

The class itself looks like this:

**InvitedView.m**

```
#import "InvitedView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface InvitedView() {
    UIButton *accept;
    UIButton *decline;
    UILabel *question;
    UIView *gray;
    ViewController *myViewController;
}

@end

@implementation InvitedView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        gray = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        NSString *holduser = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] invitedby];

        [self addSubview:gray];

        accept = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        decline = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        question = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        question.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You have been invited to a group game by %@", holduser];
        question.numberOfLines = 0;
        question.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        question.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:211.0f/255.0f green:243.0f/255.0f blue:219.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

        accept.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        accept.frame = CGRectMake(20, gray.frame.size.height / 2, (gray.frame.size.width / 2) - 10, (gray.frame.size.height / 2) - 20);
        decline.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        decline.frame = CGRectMake((gray.frame.size.width / 2) + 10, (gray.frame.size.width / 2) - 20, (gray.frame.size.width / 2) - 20, (gray.frame.size.height / 2) - 20);
        question.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, gray.frame.size.width, (gray.frame.size.height / 2) - 20);
        [question setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0]];

        [accept addTarget:myViewController action:@selector(acceptInvite) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [decline addTarget:myViewController action:@selector(declineInvite) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [gray addSubview:accept];
        [gray addSubview:decline];
        [gray addSubview:question];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The method where the view is supposed to be shown is in the view controller showing the view. It ends up getting called, I can verify that the log messages happen all the way up until the `setHidden` function:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)doSomethingWithTheNewValueOfFlagForHid {
    NSLog(@"issettingtheview******");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        NSLog(@"issettingtheviewmu2******");
        [invitedView setHidden:NO];
    });
}
```

I would like to know why `invitedView` isn't being shown after `[invitedView setHidden:NO]`.
It gets all the way to `setHidden`, and then nothing happens. I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: care to explain the downvote? or is thee a coward?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what your actual question is. I *think* that you're saying that your view does not display as expected after calling `doSomethingWithTheNewValueOfFlagForHid`. If that's the case, are you 100% certain that the `invitedView` exists in the view heirarchy and is not nil when you go to unhide it?

Comment: yes i am, as i wrote above, i instantiated it and added it to self.view and then I hid it. my question is fairly simple...why doesnt the invitedview show up? thanks. this is probably all you need to see for the problem, and all you really need to know for where i am at with it...is that I see `issettingtheviewmu2******` in console output

Comment: try to hide the view in this way.
invitedView.alpha = 0 // for hidding
and
invitedView.alpha = 1 // for showing.

Comment: hey syed...thanks i figured it out...but i have another problem related to this code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442370/uiview-elements-relevant-to-subclass-of-uiview-are-showing-up-outside-of-their-c

Comment: Even if you see your log statement, that doesn't guarantee that the view is initialized and non-nil, which appears was the issue based on the answer you posted. Breakpoints can grant a great wealth of knowledge if you use them. A breakpoint on your `setHidden:NO` line could have shown you that `invitedView` was nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ViewDidLoad`, change line to

```
[invitedView setHidden:NO];
```

to make sure you can actually see the view (frame is ok, no view above ...)

You might also want to check [Xcodes 3D View Debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)

Comment: it doesn't get displayed, so it must be something with `invitedView.m`?

Comment: Replace `invitedView = [[InvitedView alloc]...`with `invitedView = [[UIView alloc]...` to find out.

Comment: thanks so much for your help, i fixed it, I was actually instantiating the view in my viewcontroller inside an if statement by accident that wasnt getting called. thanks for the debugging tips im sure they will help in the future.

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help. Maybe you want to update or delete the question, as it will not be of any help for followers.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that it wasn't showing up, is that `invitedView` was being instantiated inside an if statement that wasn't being executed. However - shallowThought's idea to switch setHidden to YES started me down a more productive debugging tract, leading to the discovery.